# Do I need to use the word 'possible' twice in the sentence 'Automating as many lucrative tasks possible as quickly as possible.'

Tags: grammar, repetition

Or can I omit the first occurrence of the word 'possible' and just write 'Automating as many lucrative tasks as quickly as possible'?

I want the sentence to mean both the numerically highest possible amount and the quickest time frame possible as well.

Grammarly doesn't see an error in either sentence so I'm asking here.

Comment: It makes perfect sense and isn't at all unnatural to say "as many as possible as quickly as possible." They are two separate possibilities, after all. Also, don't forget the "as" between "tasks" and "possible," like you did in your question.

Answer (score 1):

*Possible lucrative tasks* (or as you put it, *lucrative tasks possible*) is a noun phrase.

*Automating as quickly as possible* is a adverbially modified verbal construct.

The two are therefore complementary in their use and the whole phrase is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that "as possible" can be understood as being distributed over the "as" terms in "as many and as quickly" in the following scheme.

- Automating  lucrative tasks, as many and as quickly as possible.

However, "Automating as many lucrative tasks as quickly as possible" seems to be wanting in some respect, that of parallelism.